# Red-Black Tree Delete Minimum

Tags: segmentation-fault, minimum, red-black-tree

I am currently trying to implement the delete function for a Red-Black Tree. The delete itself, the delete Fix up and the delete transplant work perfectly. On the other hand, I have unfortunately no clues on how to write the delete minimum function.

This is the code that I have written (just for this whole delete part):

```
struct rbtNode* RBTreeTransplant(rbtNode** root, rbtNode* u, rbtNode* v){
    if(u->parent == T_Nil){
        *root = v;
    }else if(u == u->parent->left_Child){
        u->parent->left_Child = v;
    }else{
        u->parent->right_Child = v;
    }

    v->parent = u->parent;
}

struct rbtNode* RBTreeMinimum(rbtNode* z){
    if(z->left_Child == T_Nil){ //not so sure tho
        return z;
    }

    return RBTreeMinimum(z->left_Child);
}

struct rbtNode* RBTreeDeleteFixUp(rbtNode** root, rbtNode* x){
    while(x != *root && x->color == BLACK){
        if(x == x->parent->left_Child){
            rbtNode* w = x->parent->right_Child;
            if(w->color == RED){
                w->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->color = RED;
                RBTreeLeftRotate(root,x->parent);
                w = x->parent->right_Child;
            }
            if(w->left_Child->color == BLACK && w->right_Child->color == BLACK){
                w->color = RED;
                x = x->parent;
            }else if(w->right_Child->color == BLACK){
                w->left_Child->color = BLACK;
                w->color = RED;
                RBTreeRightRotate(root,w);
                w = x->parent->right_Child;
            }
            w->color = x->parent->color;
            x->parent->color = BLACK;
            w->right_Child->color = BLACK;
            RBTreeLeftRotate(root,x->parent);
            x = *root;
        } else if(x == x->parent->right_Child){
            rbtNode* w = x->parent->left_Child;
            if(w->color == RED){
                w->color = BLACK;
                x->parent->color = RED;
                RBTreeRightRotate(root,x->parent);
                w = x->parent->left_Child;
            }
            if(w->right_Child->color == BLACK && w->left_Child->color == BLACK){
                w->color = RED;
                x = x->parent;
            }else if(w->left_Child->color == BLACK){
                w->right_Child->color = BLACK;
                w->color = RED;
                RBTreeLeftRotate(root,w);
                w = x->parent->left_Child;
            }
            w->color = x->parent->color;
            x->parent->color = BLACK;
            w->left_Child->color = BLACK;
            RBTreeRightRotate(root,x->parent);
            x = *root;
        }
        x->color = BLACK;
    }
}

//Function that deletes a node in the RBT
struct rbtNode* RBTreeDelete(rbtNode** root, rbtNode* z){
    rbtNode* x;
    rbtNode* y = z;

    if(z->left_Child == T_Nil){
        x = z->right_Child;
        RBTreeTransplant(root,z,z->right_Child);
    }else if(z->right_Child == T_Nil){
        x = z->left_Child;
        RBTreeTransplant(root,z,z->left_Child);
    }else{
        y = RBTreeMinimum(z->right_Child);
        x = y->right_Child;

        if(y->parent == z){
            x->parent = y;
        }else{
            RBTreeTransplant(root,y,y->right_Child);
            y->right_Child = z->right_Child;
            y->right_Child->parent = y;
        }

        RBTreeTransplant(root,z,y);
        y->left_Child = z->left_Child;
        y->left_Child->parent = y;
        y->color = z->color;
    }
    if(y->color == BLACK){
        RBTreeDeleteFixUp(root,x);
    }
}
```

The delete minimum function that I have written is definitely wrong, but I don't know how I can change it into a correct one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*The delete minimum function that I have written is definitely wrong, but I don't know how I can change it into a correct one.*

I don't think it is wrong. I think the code immediately after it's call is wrong.
The code

```
y = RBTreeMinimum(z->right_Child);
```

will be such that the node y (the predecessor node) will have 0-1 children.
If it has 0 children then I am not sure what

```
x = y->right_Child;
```

does. x will be NULL and therefore you cannot do

```
 x->parent = y;
```

as that is a NULL dereference.